# Get Array from Another Class

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I am working on my thesis and needed help. One part of my thesis is that i need to create a game chooser, my connection type is bluetooth, client is an android phone and server is java. Iam using JFileChooser to get the values for the array and I need to pass that array to another class. I've tried to follow this post http://www.dreaminco...ifferent-class/ but in my program i cant seem to get it work here's my code:

DemoJFileChooser (Class which I will get the Array which is path[])

```
package com.luugiathuy.apps.remotebluetooth;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DemoJFileChooser extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
   JButton go;

   JFileChooser chooser;
   String choosertitle;
   public int x=0;
   public String path[] = new String[10];

  public DemoJFileChooser() {
    go = new JButton("Do it");
    go.addActionListener(this);
    add(go);
   }

   public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
    return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

  public static void main(String s[]) {
      Thread waitThread = new Thread(new WaitThread());
        waitThread.start();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
    DemoJFileChooser panel = new DemoJFileChooser();
    frame.addWindowListener(
      new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
          System.exit(0);
          }
        }
      );
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel,"Center");
    frame.setSize(panel.getPreferredSize());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int result;

    chooser = new JFileChooser(); 
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    chooser.setDialogTitle(choosertitle);
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
       //
    // disable the "All files" option.
    //
    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    //    

    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 
      System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): " 
         +  chooser.getCurrentDirectory());
      System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : " 
         +  chooser.getSelectedFile());

          File paths = chooser.getSelectedFile();
          path[x] = paths.getAbsoluteFile().toString();
          x++; 

    for (int y=0;y<9;y++){
          System.out.println(path[y]);
          setArray(path);

    }
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("No Selection ");
      }

}
    void setArray(String paths[]) { // saves surname to variable
             path= paths; 

    }

    String[] getArray() { //gets the surname when called
          return path;
    }
}
```

ProcessConnectionThread (Class by which I need the array)

```
package com.luugiathuy.apps.remotebluetooth;

import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import com.luugiathuy.apps.remotebluetooth.DemoJFileChooser;


import javax.microedition.io.StreamConnection;

public class ProcessConnectionThread implements Runnable{
    //DemoJFileChooser path;
    //public String[] path = new String[10];

    private StreamConnection mConnection;

    // Constant that indicate command from devices
    //private static final int EXIT_CMD = -1;
    private static final int STEER_RIGHT = 1;
    private static final int STEER_LEFT = 2;
    private static final int ACCE = 3;
    private static final int REV = 4;
    private static final int MOVE = 5;
    private static final int LEFT_CLICK = 6;
    private static final int DOUBLE_CLICK = 7;
    private static final int RIGHT_CLICK = 8;
    private static final int HOLD = 9;
    private static final int RELEASE = 10;
    private static final int MOVEX = 11;
    private static final int MOVEY = 12;
    private static final int GAME = 20;
    private static final int GAME1 = 11;
    private static final int GAME2 = 12;
    private static final int GAME3 = 13;
    private static final int GAME4 = 14;
    private static final int GAME5 = 15;
    private DemoJFileChooser patharray[] = new DemoJFileChooser[10]; //create object array from student class

    public ProcessConnectionThread(StreamConnection connection)
    {
        mConnection = connection;
    }

    public void FileChooser() { //constructor use keyword public just to make sure it is visible
        for (int studI=0;studI<10;studI++) {
            patharray[studI] = new DemoJFileChooser();
        }
    } 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            // prepare to receive data
            InputStream inputStream = mConnection.openInputStream();
            OutputStream outputStream = mConnection.openOutputStream();
            System.out.println("waiting for input");

            while (true) {
                int command = inputStream.read();
                System.out.println(command);

                processCommand(command);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process the command from client
     * @param command the command code
     */
    private void processCommand(int command) {
        try {


            case GAME1:
                for (int y=0;y<10;y++){
                      patharray[y].getArray();
                      System.out.println(patharray[y]);
                }
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(patharray[0]);
                p.waitFor();



                break;


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    }
```

I am encountering an error on the for loop,patharray[].

any help/suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What does the error message say ?

Comment: http://i630.photobucket.com/albums/uu26/damnjeka/error.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to create a deep copy of an array is to use the built-in `Arrays.copyOf` family of functions.

For example:

```
String [] srcArray = { "item 1", "item 2", "item 3" };
String [] copy = Arrays.copyOf(srcArray, srcArray.length);
```

As far as your code goes, there are a few problems that jump out.  In `DemoJFileChooser.actionPerformed` you are always printing all 10 elements of the path array via `System.out.println`, but there is no guarantee that there is an object in all of those elements. You could be getting a NullPointerException here. Your for-loop should be bounded to `x`.  Also, inside that loop you are calling `setArray(path)` which means you are calling that function 10 times for no reason. Additionally, you are really doing `path = path` because you are passing `path` into `setArray` which assigns to path.

You should also be checking that `x` has not exceeded the size of `path` when you assign to it with `path[x] = paths.getAbsoluteFile().toString();`.

As a separate piece of advice, instead of doing `for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {...}` whenever you iterate over an array, you may wish to use `for(int i=0; i<theArray.length; i++) {...}` so that if you ever change the array size, you do not need to go and update the for-loops all over your program.